# The typing OR typing

Tags: articles

> Hardly did she finish **the typing** when the Manager entered the room with some more work.

Is this correct to use "the" before "typing". I checked "typing" is noun. But answer sheet explain that it should be "typing" or "the typing work". It insist on using "work" after "tying" if we want to use "the" article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be "typing", meaning the activity of using a typewriter but not referring to any specific document, or "the typing" referring to a particular typing task. It is not necessary to add the word "work". In my many years spent in offices in the days when there were typists I never once heard anyone say "the typing work"; it is  not incorrect but sounds odd.

The opening words of the sentence are not right, however: "Hardly had she finished..." is how it should start.